# Javascript sort array by context

Tags: javascript, sorting, react-select

Looking to sort a array based on context, that contains the following sample data

```
 ["1 Bob Smith", "12 Foo Bar", "112 Mary Jane", "122 Fizz Buzz"]
```

When I search by `12` it returns

```
["12 Foo Bar", "112 Mary Jane", "122 Fizz Buzz"]
```

This seems to be the default sort behaviour of [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) the library I am currently using

What I need it to return is the following

```
["12 Foo Bar", "122 Fizz Buzz", "112 Mary Jane"]
```

Comment: What does "by context" mean exactly? Are you *filtering*, not sorting? What logic is the the sorting supposed to work by?

Comment: @deceze I think they're doing both filtering and sorting, as for what they mean for _context_ I'm going to guess they want that result because `12` is at the index 0-1 in `122 Fizz Buzz` but 1-2 in `112 Mary Jane` and the default sort is sorting it as if it were numerical

Comment: @George is corrected it was filtering and sorting.  The filtering values was already done.  So it was just a matter of sorting the filtered array

Answer (score 1):

You could use the index position of the wanted search string and sort it first and then by string.

```js
var array = ["1 Bob Smith", "12 Foo Bar", "112 Mary Jane", "122 Fizz Buzz" ,"12312 something"],
    value = '12',
    result = array.filter(a => a.includes(value));

result.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.lastIndexOf(value) - b.lastIndexOf(value) || +(a > b) || -(a < b);
});

console.log(result);
```

An approach with using the indices of the search number and use it as string by sorting with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with options.

```js
var array = ["1 Bob Smith", "12 Foo Bar", "112 Mary Jane", "122 Fizz Buzz", "12312 something", "12101 bar"],
    value = '12',
    result = array.filter(a => a.includes(value));

result.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getPos(s) {
        var p = 0, h, r = [];

        s = s.match(/^\S+/)[0];
        while (p < s.length) {
            p = s.indexOf(value, p)
            r.push((p + 1) || 99999);
            if (p === -1) {
                break;
            }
            p += value.length;
        }
        return r.join(' ');
    }

    var aa = getPos(a), bb = getPos(b);

    return aa.localeCompare(bb, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' }) || a.localeCompare(b);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This seems to work for the example above but when you change the data to
 `["1 Bob Smith", "12 Foo Bar", "112 Mary Jane", "122 Fizz Buzz" ,"12312 something" ],`

The sort now returns
 `["12 Foo Bar", "122 Fizz Buzz", "12312 something", "112 Mary Jane"]`

instead of 
`["12 Foo Bar", "122 Fizz Buzz", "112 Mary Jane", "12312 something"]`

Comment: you could take the last index.

Comment: That runs into issues with `["12 Foo Bar", "122 Fizz Buzz", "112 Mary Jane", "21214 soemthigasd", "12312 something"]`

The number field portion of that ranges from 1 - 35000

Comment: please add some more use cases and the wanted order **and** why the position is selected.

Comment: So the previous edit had most of it the result from running the snippet was 
[
  "12 Foo Bar",
  "122 Fizz Buzz",
  "112 Mary Jane",
  "12312 something"
]

expected results would be
`[
  "12 Foo Bar",
  "122 Fizz Buzz",
  "12312 something"
  "112 Mary Jane", 
]`

Comment: i can not see any rule. please add some use cases with psotion and **why** the position is at this place.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by your comment.  This is for a search input field.  So the returned results need to appear as the most relevant.  It would seem requirements  are best match from left to right.

so searching for `12` would sort the list in the following order
`[12, 12123, 12101, 112]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may possibly do like;

```js
var data   = ["1 Bob Smith", "12 Foo Bar", "112 Mary Jane", "122 Fizz Buzz"],
    result = data.sort((a,b) => a.match(/\d+\s+(.+)/)[1].localeCompare(b.match(/\d+\s+(.+)/)[1]))
                 .filter(s => s.includes("12"));
console.log(result);
```